# getParameters query with variable that has white space.

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a world map in a Visualforce page and once a country is clicked on, then the action is that the user is auto-navigated to another Visualforce page (/apex/Google_Maps_Reports) which has a parameter passed to the URL.

On this Visualforce page, I have a method to the controller on that page which returns a bar chart of all Opportunities where the Account.BillingCountry is the name of the parameter passed to the URL.

In the examples, Canada is working but United States is not. I believe the latter is not working because the URL returns pc0=United+States. Is there any nice code snippet I can use to rectify this or will I have to create a custom formula field on the Account object where all values are one word, and use that instead?

```
<apex:page >

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

 data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip', p:{html:true}});var ivalue = new Array();

 data.addRows([[{v:'CA',f:'canada'},2,'']]);
 **ivalue['CA'] = 'https://cs81.salesforce.com/apex/Google_Maps_Reports_Overview?pc0=canada';**

 data.addRows([[{v:'US',f:'canada'},2,'']]);
 ivalue['CA'] = 'https://cs81.salesforce.com/apex/Google_Maps_Reports_Overview?pc0=United States';
```

Comment: TL;DR - to avoid Visualforce issues because of a passed parameter that has spaces (such as 'United States', if you are passing a country variable to the URL for example) then you can use encodeURIComponent('United States'); like: https://cs81.salesforce.com/apex/Google_Maps_Reports_Overview?pc0='+encodeURIComponent('South Africa'); and in your Apex method you can then use EncodingUtil.urlDecode to decode the encoded parameter. For example: WHERE Opportunity.Account.BillingCountry =: EncodingUtil.urlDecode(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pc0'), 'UTF-8')];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the space (and other characters that have special meaning in a URL) in the JavaScript by using [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp):

```
ivalue['CA'] = 'https://cs81.salesforce.com/apex/Google_Maps_Reports_Overview?pc0='
        + encodeURIComponent('United States');
```

or in the Apex by using [EncodingUtil.urlEncode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_urlEncode).

Comment: Thanks Keith. I tried: 'https://cs81.salesforce.com/apex/Google_Maps_Reports_Overview?pc0='+ encodeURIComponent('United States');' but to no avail. The apex method I have is: public List<Opportunity> getOppsFromGoogleMaps() {
        return [SELECT Name, Amount, CloseDate, Close_Date_DD_MM_YY__c, Owner.Name, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Opportunity.Account.BillingCountry =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pc0')];
    } &I'm unclear how I could encode this via the EncodingUtil.urlEncode method...because the URL variable will always be different as pc0 is different? Many thanks

Comment: @AndyHitchings My comment about `EncodingUtil.urlEncode` more related to generating the JavaScript URL but I now assume that the JavaScript is hard coded. If the problem is that you are getting 'United+States' back in your `getOppsFromGoogleMaps` method then you can remove the encoding in that method using `EncodingUtil.urlDecode(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pc0'), 'UTF-8')`.

Comment: Thnaks a lot, Keith. In my vf page I have: data.addRows([[{v:'US',f:'USA'},2,'']]);
 ivalue['US'] = mysalesforceinstance/apex/Google_Maps_Reports_Overview?pc0='+encodeURIComponent('United States'); and in my method I now have: public List<Opportunity> getOppsFromGoogleMaps() {
        return [SELECT Name, Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE Opportunity.Account.BillingCountry =: EncodingUtil.urlDecode(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pc0'), 'UTF-8')];
    }, but the URL being returned is still 'pc0=United+States'. Do you have any idea where I am going wrong? Many thanks

Comment: @AndyHitchings The URL should contain the + but when the query is done in the controller the + should be removed by the EncodingUtil.urlDecode.

Comment: Hi Keith - thank you so much - everything is working as expected. I realized that there must have been too many results per the bar chart in the Visualforce page as when I tried it with other examples like 'South Africa', the Opportunities were being displayed. I amended the SOQL with a LIMIT and tried again with 'United States', and it is working now. Thanks a lot, again!